# extract "style" information when scraping data in html using XML in R

Tags: xml, r, web-scraping

I used the script below to try to extract the data from a HTML file converted from PDF.

```
temp.html <- scan(file=filename,what="character")
pagetree <- htmlTreeParse(temp.html, error=function(...){}, useInternalNodes = TRUE)
tx.raw <- getNodeSet(pagetree,"//div")
```

The `tx.raw` create a list and one of them is shown as below:

```
tx[[170]]

[[170]]
<div style="position:absolute;top:985;left:748">
  <nobr>
    <span class="ft03"> 




971.72
 </span>
  </nobr>
</div>
```

The information I need is inside `span` (i.e. `971.72`), but I also need to `style` in `div` to let me know where exactly the piece is data in `span` is located in the pdf file. How can I extract the style information also? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do that with a simple **regexp**:

```
sub('.*style="([0-9a-z;:]*)".*', '\\1', t)
```

Where `t` holds the corresponding HTML part as text.

---

Lengthy example based on your demo HTML part:

```
## loading your demo HTML part to one line
t <- paste(readLines(textConnection('<div style="position:absolute;top:985;left:748">
  <nobr>
    <span class="ft03">




971.72
 </span>
  </nobr>
</div>')), collapse = '')

## let us extract some parts!
library(XML)
t.html <- htmlTreeParse(t, useInternalNodes = TRUE)
t.val <- xpathApply(t.html, '//div', xmlValue)
t.val <- gsub('\\s', '', t.val)
t.style <- sub('.*style="([0-9a-z;:]*)".*', '\\1', t)
```

Depending on how you parse the HTML before, most of the above lines can be eliminated - of course.

**Results:**

```
> t.val
[1] "971.72"
> t.style
[1] "position:absolute;top:985;left:748"
```

Extracting `top` and `left` could be addressed similarly, I've just not deal with it as I am not sure if e.g. `left` and `top` are static strings.